# std::prev_permutation and DRY principle

Tags: c++, stl, dry

```
std::string s="abc";
std::prev_permutation(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::greater<char>());
```

gives the same result as

```
std::string s="abc";
std::next_permutation(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::less<char>());
```

Why is `std::prev_permutation` present in the STL? Doesn't it break the DRY principle?

Comment: DRY isn't about features being redundant to each other. DRY is about not writing the same thing more than once. If `prev_permutation` and `next_permutation` happen to be a copy/paste of each other, with a comparison reversed, that would violate DRY. But `prev_permutation` and `next_permutation` might share a common implementation they forward the call to, in which case DRY is respected. And for a library, DRY only matters to the maintainer. As a library user, it shouldn't matter if your library's implementer follow DRY or not.